# Importing MultiIndex csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, multi-index

I'm trying to import a MultiIndex CSV into Python, which has the following structure:
[image]

I tried to import the file:

```
CMF = pd.read_csv("./ConstantMaturityFutures_2.csv", header=[0,1])
CMF.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0_level_1": ""}, inplace=True)
CMF["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(CMF["Date"])
CMF.set_index("Date", inplace =True)
CMF
```

However, I get the Blank level 0 headers of DTM get replaced by "Unnamed: x_level_x".

[image]

Is there a way to create a MultiIndex dataframe from this CSV?

PS: I have seen many solutions where they manually define the headers. This is not an option for me since I have about 1000 columns. Moreover, the NaN in the data is correct.

Many thanks!

Comment: The structure you see is due to how excel or some other program renders the csv; the underlying data probably looks very different with the header being `data,,data1,,...` so pandas sees blanks and does what's natural for it.  You should save the csv properly so the headers are output for every cell, or you'll be forced to fix this with pandas, which is more complicated

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem!